# C++ 10 Seattle Embarcadero Type complex_array

Tags: c++, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

I'm trying to work with the open source code from MSVC called NEC2++
https://github.com/tmolteno/necpp

There is an undefined type called complex_array which Builder can't recognize. I have Boost installed but I don't see this type anywhere in the documentation. I am assuming this is a type for an array for real and imaginary numbers. I can not find such a type in Builder or Boost documentation.

I'm looking for possible solutions to port this code.

Comment: Bring the code here.

Answer (score 2):

`complex_array` is a custom class defined in NEC2++'s [`math_util.h`](https://github.com/tmolteno/necpp/blob/master/src/math_util.h) header file:

```
#if USING_EIGEN_ARRAY
  #include <Eigen/Dense>

  typedef Eigen::Matrix<int32_t, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>  int_array;
  typedef Eigen::Matrix<nec_float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>  real_array;
  typedef Eigen::Matrix<nec_complex, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>  complex_array; // <-- here
#else
  // Use our own types rather than Eigen
  #include "safe_array.h"
  typedef safe_array<int32_t>  int_array;
  typedef safe_array<nec_float>  real_array;
  typedef safe_array<nec_complex>  complex_array; // <-- here

  typedef safe_matrix<int32_t>  int_matrix;
  typedef safe_matrix<nec_float>  real_matrix;
  typedef safe_matrix<nec_complex>  complex_matrix;
#endif
```

Whatever code you are compiling that claims `complex_array` is undefined is missing an `#include` statement for `math_util.h`.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I had simply copied this header file wrong.

Comment: @kc3ase, I was trying to figure out something similar and this is what I came up with: complex_array is a safe_array<nec_float> and nec_float is a double.  nec_complex is a std::complex<double>.